# Why are Yahoo Finance API values different from the web interface?

Tags: yahoofinance

(**SOLVED**: Solution is below the second graph)

The API results on `GSPC`:
[image]

Same period in the interactive chart of `^GSPC`:
[image]

## SOLVED

Apparently, Yahoo Finance API has different results for `^GSPC` and `GSPC`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking at the actual Close values or the Adjusted Close values in the API values? The Interactive chart shows the `Adjusted Close` values which account for dividends/splits/other corporate events. More on how `Adjusted Close` is calculated from actual `Close` [here](http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/06/adjustedclosingprice.asp).